# Interceptor on CustomerData/Cart.php

Tags: magento2

I can't do a interceptor on CustomerData/Cart.php and I don't know why.
Check my di.xml

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart">
        <plugin name="newValues" type="Vendor\MinicartValues\Plugin\CustomerData" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

My Class:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\MinicartValues\Plugin;

class CustomerData {

      public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, $result)
      {
        $totals = $subject->getQuote()->getTotals();
        $fp = fopen('/src/www/var/log/log.txt','a+');
        fwrite($fp, var_export($totals,true));
        fclose($fp);
        $result['grandtotal'] = isset($totals['grand_total'])
        ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['grand_total']->getValue())
        : 0;
        $result['shipping'] = isset($totals['shipping'])
        ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['shipping']->getValue())
        : 0;
        return $result;
      }
  }
```

I simply can't figure out why that won't work. I put a log on the original class

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php
```

and always go into this never go to my interceptor.
My `magento version is "2.1.8"`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you add a sequence so the module is loaded after checkout module. Besides that you have to trigger an update of the section to check if your code is working, example click on the update cart button on the cart page

Comment: Where did you place the di.xml?

Comment: I put the di.xml on Vendor/MyModule/etc/di.xml.
I didn't put Sequence to load the module maybe is that the problem? I'll try and comeback here.

Comment: Maybe i should put the di.xml on etc/frontend/di.xml like magento-wee did ya? Will try

Comment: That should not be the problem but try the sequence, let me know if you need anymore help

Comment: Did it work to add a sequence?

Comment: No, I've change a lot of things and nothing works. But i found the problem, the $subject->getQuote probably was getting a error but this new magento 2 don't show the errors on that kind of class so I just broken my head and nothing work. When i implements this method "getQuote" on the current context "the object" and shazam. Thanks anyway

Comment: Next time use mage2gen.com to generate the plugin and you won't have this problem any more

Comment: Nice dude thanks. The answer here it's becouse "getQuote" is a protected method so i shouldn't access him from the $subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here is:

```
class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart
{
    public function afterGetSectionData(\Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $subject, $result)
    {
        $totals = $this->getQuote()->getTotals();
        $result['grandtotal'] = isset($totals['grand_total'])
        ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['grand_total']->getValue())
        : 0;
        $result['shipping'] = isset($totals['shipping'])
        ? $this->checkoutHelper->formatPrice($totals['shipping']->getValue())
        : 0;
        return $result;
    }  
}
```

I think the problem was on the calling the interceptor, but it was aways called. The problem was the `getQuote` method is "protected" and I wasn't extending the Cart class, so i did it and now it's all ok.